# RESTful api with /products and /myproducts

Tags: api, rest

I'm building a website where users can sell products. I'm beginning with a RESTful api, so  far I have:

```
/Product (Accepts, post)
/Product/[product_id] (Accepts, get, put, delete)
```

I also want to list all of the products for all users, so I'm thinking of having:

```
/Products (Accepts, get)
```

and here's my problem, I also want the user to view their own products, so I'm also thinking of having:

```
/MyProducts (Accepts, get)
```

I just think that having /Products & /MyProducts are kind of the same, except they are filtered on the user, so what method should I use to do this?

I've thought about the below, but don't know if this is frowned upon:

```
/Products (Accepts, get) <- returns all products
/Products/[user_id] (Accepts, get) <- returns all products for a user id.
```

Any help, pointers or guidance extremely welcomed!

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Im interested, has anything come out of this product selling service? where is it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplify drastically. There are really only two resources you need:

- Something to represent a collection of products, URI: `/products`
- Something to represent a single product, URI: `/products/{id}`

All your needs can be met with just those two resources:

- To see every product in the system: `GET /products`
- To see just your own products: `GET /products?showOnlyMine=true`
- To create a new product: `POST /products` which returns a `Location` of `/products/{id}`
- To see a single product: `GET /products/{id}`

Feel free to use a different URI parameter than `showOnlyMine`, of course.